# How to do a swipe action to a test in espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

Espresso has the swipe action, I want to know if is possible to make a swipe left or right action until a text is visible on the screen. I mean if I have a Tab layout with a lot of tabs, I want to execute the swipe action until a Tab with an specific text is visible

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a just a loop that makes the swipe and then checks that this element is visible in a try/catch block until you reach the end of the pageview or the item is found.

If the end of the pageview is reached and the item is not found then you can do something like *Assert.fail("The element has not been found.");*

Try this code:

```
boolean found = false;
int i = 0;
while (!found && i < NUM_PAGES) {
    onView(withId(R.id.viewPager)).perform(swipeLeft());
    SystemClock.sleep(500);

    try {
        if (checkElementVisible()) {
            found = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // The search continues
    }
    i++;
}

if (!found) {
    Assert.fail("The element has not been found.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can swipe once and verify if your textView is displayed. If not, swipe again.

Or you can have a method in which you verify for your textview...and if "NoMatchingViewException" is thrown, you swipe.

Something like this(didn't test the code):

```
    public static boolean swipeUntilExists(int resourceId) {
    final ViewInteraction uiElement = onView(withId(resourceId));
    boolean isVisible = false;
    while (!isVisible) {
        try {

            // do swipe here

            uiElement.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
            isVisible = true;
        } catch (NoMatchingViewException e) {
            // do nothing here
        }
    }
    return isVisible;
}
```